# PyroCMS - Storing stream data in multiple languages

Tags: multilingual, pyrocms

I have a client who requires me to store the stream data in two different languages. For example, a stream for FAQ with fields: question and answer would have:

```
English Version:
Question: _Some question in english_
Answer: _Some answer in english_
```

and then:

```
Italian Version:
Question: _Some question in italian_
Answer: _Some answer in italian_
```

I know that PyroCMS support multi-lingual support for backend and front-end labels but how do I make sure that stream data can be store in two different languages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create a field for save the language, for example (lang) and select the  [**Pyro Lang FieldType**](http://docs.pyrocms.com/2.2/manual/developers/tools/streams-api/core-field-types#pyro-lang)

Next, you can looping your stream making a where with the new field as column, for example:

```
where lang = 'es'
```

You can too use the [Lang plugin](http://docs.pyrocms.com/2.2/manual/plugins/lang) for know the current lang of your site. Use the `{{ lang:code }}` tag for this.